How to find the order of a field modulo polynomial?
I know how to find the order of a finite field.  But how do you do it with a finite field modulo a polynomial $m(x)$ ? For example how do you find the order of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]_{x^3+2x^2+1}$ ?

It's a consequence of division with remainder that $K[x]/p$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension $\deg p$ (or, in case $p=0$, of dimension $\aleph_0$). Whether or not it's a field, it depends on $p$.

$x^2+x+1$ is not  prime, so this won't be a field, but the order will be, as a ring, $p^{\deg(m)},$ in general

@ThomasAndrews:  OP has $x^3+2x^2+1$

Even better than my previous link: this question is an exact duplicate of Polynomials, finite fields and cardinality/dimension considerations (found using the search engine of MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=dimension+and+cardinality).

Hint: your polynomial is irreducible (plug in $0,1$ and $2$, they are not a zero.) Hence the quotient is a field and isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{27}$.

Sure, after an edit. @tanner You're here long enough to know how this works.
